# Use bot calling endpoint to listen to meetings/calls between users

Tags: c#, botframework, microsoft-teams

I am working with bot framework for a MS Teams app, i know that bots can interact with users using messages and join calls(beta). Is there a way WITHOUT inviting the bot to the call, but it being installed to a channel in a specific Teams tenant to listen to calls though a web hook or something similar? I just need to hookup the call and send to a client subscriber in order to notify users that they are receiving a call in Teams.

Comment: Currently, only support we have is [calls and online meetings bots](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/calls-and-meetings/calls-meetings-bots-overview). I will check and get back if there is any plans to have webhooks.

Comment: @Wajeed-MSFT Thank you. I will be waiting.